# Push a local branch as a new remote branch that was based on a remote branch

Tags: git

I'm new to version control and having a hard time on this one.

So, I have this branch in the remote called `check-fallback`,

and I wanted to create a local branch based on that one because my task is somewhat close and requires most works on that branch.

So what I did was, `git checkout -b check-fallback-subtask origin/check-fallback`

Now, I have `check-fallback-subtask` as a local branch, worked on it, `git add .`, and `git commit`ed.
Now, when I push, git returns the following instructions, which I'm not really sure which to follow.

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:check-fallback

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

What I just want is to peacefully(lol) push my local `check-fallback-subtask` into the remote repo as a new branch.

How do I do that? Please bear with me since I'm new to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you never checked out `check-fallback` locally before. So when you created `check-fallback-subtask`, git automatically associated your local branch with `origin/check-fallback`. To change this association, you just need to supply some details to `git push` and override the defaults:

```
git push --set-upstream origin check-fallback-subtask:check-fallback-sutask
```

You only need to do this the once. Then you can `git push` as usual. See `git help push` for more details.

To avoid issues like these, I generally create branches on the remote (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc.) through their web UI. Then I will `git fetch` locally and `git checkout` the branch I created.

Comment: will it affect the original remote branch that I created it from?

Comment: @jthinam No, this will create a new branch with the name specified after the `:`.

Comment: @jthinam I think you can omit the `:` and everything after. By specifying the branch name explicitly, git will use the same name on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

[Code-Apprentice's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505368/112968), but if you only need a one-off push of a local branch to a specific remote branch, you can you the following command:

```
git push origin local:remote
```

e.g.

```
git push origin check-fallback-subtask:check-fallback-subtask
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this command:

```
git checkout -b check-fallback-subtask origin/check-fallback
```

When you create a new branch and specify to start from a remote tracking branch (in this case `origin/*`) then by default it will track that branch. You can specify to not track it like this:

```
git checkout -b check-fallback-subtask origin/check-fallback --no-track
```

And then it will not be tracking anything yet, and act just like you had branched off of local branch, such as your local `check-fallback`.

Note, when you created your branch, you probably saw a message like this:

```
Switched to a new branch 'check-fallback-subtask'
branch 'check-fallback-subtask' set up to track 'origin/check-fallback'.
```

Next time you see that it might remind you that you need to change your upstream branch to something else. You can also type `git status` at any time to see if your local branch is tracking a remote branch yet.